# What is the error SQL syntax when click on a tag on opencart?

Tags: php, sql, opencart

I'm having this error when click on a tag on product page on my Opencart 2.3.0.2 store

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OR man.name LIKE '%%' pd.tag LIKE '%conjunto%' AND pd.tag LIKE '%infantil%' AND ' at line 1<br />Error No: 1064<br />SELECT p.product_id, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM oc_review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, (SELECT price FROM oc_product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '1' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, (SELECT price FROM oc_product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '1' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priori in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cabanins\system\library\db\mysqli.php on line 40
```

I dont know what the reason for this error is because my localhost version is working normally.

Comment: When asking for OpenCart help, always include: 1. exact OpenCart version (you have), 2. theme used, 3. extensions used.

Comment: Opencart 2.3.0.2 and theme themeforest marketshop

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is right here:

```
man.name LIKE '%%' pd.tag
```

You need to include a AND tag like so

```
man.name LIKE '%%' AND pd.tag
```

Although there's no reason to have

```
man.name LIKE '%%'
```

as %% will match EVERYTHING.

So you could just make it:

```
OR pd.tag LIKE '%conjunto%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me. I dont understand why the code is wrong only on online version and works fine on localhost. Im using the same code. Thats the code

```
if (!empty($data['filter_category_id'])) {
        if (!empty($data['filter_sub_category'])) {
            $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category_path cp LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c ON (cp.category_id = p2c.category_id)";
        } else {
            $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c";
        }

        if (!empty($data['filter_filter'])) {
            $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_filter pf ON (p2c.product_id = pf.product_id) LEFT JOIN ".$from." p ON (pf.product_id = p.product_id)";
        } else {
            $sql .= " LEFT JOIN ".$from." p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id)";
        }
    } else {
        $sql .= " FROM ".$from." p";
    }

    $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '" . (int) $this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int) $this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'";

    if (!empty($data['filter_category_id'])) {
        if (!empty($data['filter_sub_category'])) {
            $sql .= " AND cp.path_id = '" . (int) $data['filter_category_id'] . "'";
        } else {
            $sql .= " AND p2c.category_id = '" . (int) $data['filter_category_id'] . "'";
        }

        if (!empty($data['filter_filter'])) {
            $implode = array();

            $filters = explode(',', $data['filter_filter']);

            foreach ($filters as $filter_id) {
                $implode[] = (int) $filter_id;
            }

            $sql .= " AND pf.filter_id IN (" . implode(',', $implode) . ")";
        }
    }

    if (!empty($data['filter_name']) || !empty($data['filter_tag'])) {
        $sql .= " AND (";

        if (!empty($data['filter_name'])) {
            $implode = array();

            $words = explode(' ', trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $data['filter_name'])));

            foreach ($words as $word) {
                $implode[] = "pd.name LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($word) . "%'";
            }

            if ($implode) {
                $sql .= " " . implode(" AND ", $implode) . "";
            }

            if (!empty($data['filter_description'])) {
                $sql .= " OR pd.description LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_name']) . "%'";
            }
        }

        if (!empty($data['filter_name']) && !empty($data['filter_tag'])) {
            $sql .= " OR ";
        }

        if (!empty($data['filter_tag'])) {
            $implode = array();

            $words = explode(' ', trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $data['filter_tag'])));

            foreach ($words as $word) {
                $implode[] = "pd.tag LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($word) . "%'";
            }

            if ($implode) {
                $sql .= " " . implode(" AND ", $implode) . "";
            }
        }

        if (!empty($data['filter_name'])) {
            if($multiplicar_produtos) {
            $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.model) LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "%'";
            } else {
            $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.model) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
            }
            $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.sku) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
            $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.upc) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
            $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.ean) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
            $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.jan) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
            $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.isbn) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
            $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.mpn) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
        }

        $sql .= ")";
    }
```